# Django: dependencies reference nonexistent parent node

Tags: python, django, migrate

When I run the following command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I receive this error from django so can't step forward in my practice:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/nikhil/testWeb-devEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/nikhil/testWeb-devEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/nikhil/testWeb-devEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/nikhil/testWeb-devEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/nikhil/testWeb-devEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 63, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/home/nikhil/testWeb-devEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/nikhil/testWeb-devEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/nikhil/testWeb-devEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 241, in build_graph
    self.graph.add_dependency(migration, key, parent)
  File "/home/nikhil/testWeb-devEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 42, in add_dependency
    raise KeyError("Migration %s dependencies reference nonexistent parent node %r" % (migration, parent))
KeyError: u"Migration testBolt.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'delivery_boy', u'0004_auto_20150221_2011')"
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: So, do you have a migration called 0004_auto_20150221_2011 in the delivery_boy app?

Comment: There is no migration 0004_auto_20150221_2011 in my delivery_boy app.

Comment: Well, that explains the error, then. Now you need to remove that reference from frshBolt.0001_initial and investigate why you have that dependency in the first place.

Comment: @DanielRoseman can you please add it as an answer so it can be accepted (and question resolved) ?

Comment: From the error message we can see that the error is caused by frshBolt.0001_initial dependencies. Removing frshBolt.migrations fixed the issue for me..

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Solution - 1**

Remove `pyc` files from your migrations folder.

**Solution - 2**

Need to remove that reference from `testBolt.0001_initial` by editing migration file.

**Solution - 3**

1. Remove the new changes from the models and run `python manage.py migrate --fake`
2. Now again modify your models with new changes
3. Run `python manage.py makemigrations`
4. And then again run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: If removing pyc files could solve the problem, you should do it as first option. Continue with other proposed solutions if it doesn't help. So I would suggest to reorder solutions here.

Comment: @smido Hello as per your comment I'm arrange solution.

Comment: I am not all sure this is the best solution, or the solution intended for this type of problem. I came here because I got the same traceback, but I don't know why you got yours. I got mine because I wanted to change a table name and did so in the OS. According to the docs, there is a method expressly designed for changing table names. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/schema-editor/#alter-db-table . Is this the cause of your issue?

Comment: I had to go further: remove my change, remove all migration files (keep the `__init__.py`). Run `makemigrations` to create the initial one. Run `makemigations --fake`. Add in my changes, run `makemigrations`, and finally `migrate`.

Comment: `makemigration` doesn't accept that argument: `makemigrations: error: unrecognized arguments: --fake`

Answer (score 15):

In my case, I had the `.py` extension in the dependency module name, like this:

```
dependencies = [
    ('dashboard', '0003_auto_20181024_0603.py'),
    ('auth', '__latest__'),
    ('contenttypes', '__latest__'),
]
```

I removed the `.py`, changing the line to this

```
    ('dashboard', '0003_auto_20181024_0603'),
```

and that fixed it.

Comment: This fixed my issue - I had followed a tutorial that just had `'name'` in the dependencies list, rather than `('name', '__latest__')`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. In my case, because I played with migrations manually, I forgot to create `__init__.py` inside of `migrations` folder.

Answer (score 9):

This works for me 
In your app migrations folder

1. Delete all the files pyc in your app folder (except the `__init__`)
2. Delete all the files in the migrations (except the `__init__` )
3. `python manage.py makemigrations`
4. `python manage.py migrate`
5. `runserver`

Comment: WARNING: Don't do this in production, or any environment where you need to keep records in your database table. It's fine if you are just messing around on Localhost.

Comment: As long as the comment by @MichaelRomrell isn't the first line of the answer itself, the answer needs to be downvoted, not upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar case, running django in windows in a virtual env. In my case the missing dependency was 0001_initial - which was definitely there in the migration folder.

The 'solution' was to remove the pyc files and do another migrate attempt.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how it worked for me:

1. Deleted all the `__pycache__` folders inside every app.
2. Deleted all the files inside the migration folder except for `__init.py__` inside each app folder.
3. `python manage.py makemigrations`
4. `python manage.py migrate`
5. `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 4):

I tried NIKHIL's solutions with no luck. What did work for me was:

- **Removing my virtual environment**
- Deleting the migration `__pycache__` folders
- Deleting old migrations
- Recreating my virtual environment
- Running migrations

Answer (score 4):

```
KeyError: u"Migration testBolt.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'delivery_boy', u'0004_auto_20150221_2011')"
```

Remove

> testBolt.0001_initial

then run migrate again

Comment: this worked for me just delete the offending migration and migrations run fine.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have activated your virtual environment.

Comment: Its the solution if you get error from django's migration, for example : `... initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'auth', u'0008_alter_user_username_max_length')`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

- Delete environment.
- Crearte new environment with all dependencies

Comment: Wow! I don't know how it has solved my one!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had moved around my virtual environment folder.so I moved it back where it was, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just uninstalled Django and reinstalled it:

```
pip3 uninstall Django

pip3 install Django
```

then migrated

Answer (score 0):

There could be some migration files remaining in the app when you tried the migrate command. First remove all `migrations` directories from all the modules. For other cases Nikhil Rane has covered it all.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

- Remove the current virtual environment and create your new virtual environment.
- Run this command in the project directory to remove all migration files -
  `find . -type d -name "__pycache__" -exec rm -rf "{}" \;`
- Remove database file `.sqlite3`
- Now run the migrations using: `python manage.py makemigrations`
- Migrate the migrations: `python manage.py migrate`

Basically, all the below steps are common and I think all have gone through these steps but if you're missing the first step i.e., to recreate the virtual environment then must give a try to it.

Comment: `find` command in the answer will produce "No such file or directory" errors for nested folders. To avoid that, replace "\" sign with "+" sign in the end of the command, e.g. `find . -type d -name "__pycache__" -exec rm -rf "{}" +;`

Answer (score -2):

Go to folder testBolt -> migrations and remove 0001_initial py and pyc files.

Comment: This does not address a situation where you are removing a deprecated app/module.  If you remove the '0001' migration, you will have to remove '0002' as it usually depends on 0001...and so on until you have removed all your migrations...