# Could not make migrations after deleting db.sqlite3 Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

After doing so many change in models, I could not access database.So, I applied this solution:

delete all migrations and db.sqlite3 database and make 
 migrations again.

But, unfortunately it doesn't work.

I got the error like this:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-  packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line 
    utility.execute()
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-ackages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 96, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 274, in build_graph
    raise exc
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 244, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 261, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 261, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
 File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 104, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
 django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration taggit.0003_tag_tags dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('personal', '0006_auto_20171113_1322')
```

How can I make migrations again??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668351/django-dependencies-reference-nonexistent-parent-node

Comment: I tried all the solutions given in youe link.

Comment: same error generated, after applying this solutions

Comment: remove all migrations and then try again with makemigrations and migrate

Comment: I removed all the migrations and also db.sqlite3. now, I am not able to run any migrations